Not able to use %matplotlib qt5 in vscode in ubuntu 24.04
I am not able to use %matplotlib qt5
In jupyter notebook(vscode) while doing...
import  numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
%matplotlib qt5

I am getting errors:
ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7, PyQt5, PyQt6, PySide >= 1.0.3, PySide2, or
    PySide6 is available, and only one is imported per session.

    Currently-imported Qt library:                              'pyqt5'
    PyQt5 available (requires QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QtWidgets): False
    PyQt6 available (requires QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QtWidgets): False
    PySide2 installed:                                          False
    PySide6 installed:                                          False
    Tried to load:                                              ['pyqt5']

It was working fine in ubuntu 22.04 but not in 24.04.
Any help is highly appreciated...
Tried installing pyqt5, but still not working
